# Tabs, Spaces and digits Removal

Tags: c#

I have a documents which have many sentences and each word in a sentence is precedes with a digit+a single tab followed by two tabs e.g

```
4[one tab]Sun[two tabs] 5 [one tab]is[two tabs] 6[one tabs] rising[two tabs]
```

I used the following code but it does not work

```
string strLine = sr.ReadLine();  
resultString = Regex.Replace(strLine, @"( |\t|\r?\n)\s\1+", " ");
```

I need out put like this "Sun is rising"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(strLine, @"[\s\d]+", " ");
```

to replace Tabs, Spaces and Digits with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using  System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String strLine="4   Sun     5   is      6   rising";
        String resultString = Regex.Replace(strLine, @"\d\t", "");
        resultString= Regex.Replace(resultString, @"\t\t", " ");
        Console.Write(resultString);
   }
}
```